# Find MAX value on ALN field with special characters in DB2

Tags: db2

Determine the max value of an attribute that has values like below,

```
GROUPNAME
 A-1000
 C-1001
 A-1002
Expected Output 
 1002
```

I tried the below query, and it is giving the output as 1001 instead of 1002, the max value is based on the alphabet rather than the number,

```
select max(groupname) from table where type in ('A','C') and customer is null
Output 
1001
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a limit query here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE type IN ('A', 'C') AND customer IS NULL
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(groupname, INSTR(groupname, '-') + 1) AS INT) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The strategy above is to isolate the number which comes after the dash, cast it to an integer, then use that for sorting.